# Force figure placement in Subsection of LaTeX

Tags: floats, diagrams, placeins

The LaTeX document (documentclass:article) is having sections and subsections. The figures are to be placed to appear in the desired subsection only. I am using

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

It forces to appear figures in the respective section. I want something like

```
\usepackage[subsection]{placeins}
```

which will force LaTeX to place images in subsection rather than in section. How could this be done?

Comment: How about option `[H]` for the intended figure(s)?

Comment: It doesn't work...even with or without placeins

Comment: It doesn't work?! Easy to say when there is no `MWE`!

Comment: YOU decide where the figures are placed. You can let LaTeX make the decision where to place a figure, which seems not to be what you want

Comment: @user61681 `[H]` need the float package. Anyway, we aware that force float positions too much could have sides effects in the layout worse that left a figure out of the subsection where it is referenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is what worked for me.

```
  \usepackage{placeins}
    ...
    \begin{figure}
    ...
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier
```

The command *Floatbarrier* is to be included after *end{figure}* This forced every image to appear in the respective subsection. I know it is not in the spirit of LaTeX to use this. However it might be requirement sometimes...

Comment: This causes an almost undebuggable `Output routine didn't use all of \box255` error for my simple use-case :(